# Move from Windows Form App to Windows Form App (.Net framework) - Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I create a form in Visual Studio (Visual Basic), everything works fine, but when I tried to add a Database on this, I found out that I made it on Windows Forms App instead of Windows Forms App (.NET Framework). Is there a way to migrate this project instead of start all over again?

Got no possitive results

Comment: What do you mean "add a Database on this"? What error are you getting? The type of project you select is irrelevant to connecting to a database.

Comment: Putting aside the fact you can use a database with either type of WinForms project, if you really want to use .NET Framework, you have to start over.

Comment: You don't have to start over. Create a new .NET Framework project and add the form you created to the new project. There will unlikely be any change you'll have to make to the form or designer code. I have forms that I use in both .NET 7 and .NET Framework projects without any issues.

Comment: so there is no way to migrate the project to .Net Framework

Comment: How do I add the new form, kind of new on this

Comment: You have to create a new project, but the code doesn't have to be rewritten.

Comment: In Visual Studio, "Project" menu -> "Add existing item".

Comment: I was able to do it, I did not need to rewrite the code, thanks, but the form shows empty as if it is new.

Answer (score 0):

You can just directly copy and paste the Form from your old project to your new project in the Solution Explorer.